# Aplicar Datatables a 2 Tablas llenadas con Ajax que están en la misma página

Tags: ajax, datatables

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con la aplicación de DataTables a dos tablas que se encuentran en la misma página, se aplica correctamente el diseño de DataTables en las tablas, pero en la tabla de abajo, en mi segunda tabla me sale el mensaje de “No data available in table” como si la tabla no tuviera datos y pues si filtro en la segunda tabla la que manda el mensaje no filtra y si le doy a exportar exporta la tabla vacía.
Espero que me puedan apoyar.

> Tabla 1 arriba

```html
<div class="row">
    <!-- Column -->
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Artículos de la Venta</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Add class <code>.table-hover</code></h6>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover" id="tabla_get_articulos_venta">
                        <thead>
                            <tr id="tr_tablita">
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Código</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Precio</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Movimientos</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Tabla 2 abajo

```html
<div class="row">
    <!-- Column -->
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Artículos del Sistema</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Add class <code>.table-hover</code></h6>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover" id="tabla_get_articulos">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Código</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Precio</th>
                                <th>Proveedor</th>
                                <th>Movimientos</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Declaro variable para obtener DataTables ya que después la quiero
>   destruir.

```js
var tabla_get_articulos_venta;
```

> Lleno tabla de abajo

```js
function get_articulos() {

            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('Ventas_controller/get_articulos')?>",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    // console.log(data);
                        // if (data.respuesta == exito){
                    var contador_art = 1;

                    var filas = data.length;
                    for (  i = 0 ; i < filas; i++){ //cuenta la cantidad de registros
                        var nuevafila= "<tr><td>" +
                        contador_art + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].codigo + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].descripcion + "</td><td>" +
                        "$ "+data[i].precioCompra + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].proveedor + "</td><td>"+
                        "<a type='button' onclick='add_articulo_venta("+data[i].ideArticulo+")' class='btn btn-success'>" +
                            "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>" +
                        "</a>" +"</td><td>" ;

                        $("#tabla_get_articulos").append(nuevafila);
                        contador_art++;
                    }

                    // tabla_get_articulos = $('#tabla_get_articulos').DataTable( {
                    //     dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    //     buttons: [
                    //         'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                    //     ]
                    // } );
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error");
                    // swal({
                    //   title: "Error!",
                    //   text: "No se trajo la información de la empresa!",
                    //   icon: "error",
                    //   button: true,
                    //   dangerMode: false,
                    // })
                    // .then((willDelete) => {
                    //   if (willDelete) {
                    //     $('#modalEdit').modal('show');
                    //   }
                    // });
                }
            });
        }
```

> Lleno tabla de arriba y ejecuto el DataTables

```js
function get_articulos_venta(id_venta) {

            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('Ventas_controller/get_articulos_venta')?>/"+id_venta,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                        // if (data.respuesta == exito){

                    var filas = data.length;
                    for (  i = 0 ; i < filas; i++){ //cuenta la cantidad de registros
                        var nuevafila = "<tr><td>" +
                        contador + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].codigo + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].descripcion + "</td><td>" +
                        "$ "+data[i].precioCompra + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].cantidad + "</td><td>"+
                        data[i].preciototal + "</td><td>"+
                        "<a type='button' onclick='delete_articulo_venta("+data[i].ideDetalleVenta+")' class='btn btn-danger'>" +
                            "<i class='fa fa-times'></i>" +
                        "</a> " +
                        "<a type='button' onclick='get_info_articulo_venta("+data[i].ideDetalleVenta+")'  class='btn btn-warning'>" +
                            "<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>" +
                        "</a>" +"</td></tr>" ;

                        $("#tabla_get_articulos_venta").append(nuevafila);
                        contador++;
                    }

                    tabla_get_articulos_venta = $('table.table-hover').DataTable( {
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
                            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ]
                    } );
                    // $('#tabla_get_articulos_venta').html(nuevafila);

                    // contador--;
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error");
                    // swal({
                    //   title: "Error!",
                    //   text: "No se trajo la información de la empresa!",
                    //   icon: "error",
                    //   button: true,
                    //   dangerMode: false,
                    // })
                    // .then((willDelete) => {
                    //   if (willDelete) {
                    //     $('#modalEdit').modal('show');
                    //   }
                    // });
                }
            });
        }
```

> Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que la tabla de abajo sale el mensaje mencionado y por ende no filtra y exporta datos vacíos porque marca que la tabla esta vacía.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es más sencillo de lo que parece, estás haciendo un `append` al final de la tabla, lo que deberías hacer es un `append` al `tbody` de la misma, ya que este es el cuerpo de la tabla, reemplaza el append de la siguiente forma:

```
$("#tabla_get_articulos tbody").append(nuevafila);
```

En teoría eso debes hacer con ambas tablas, me parece curioso que al parecer una funcionara, por favor prueba y me cuentas. Espero sea útil.

Comment: en cual de las dos funciones lo coloco, en la funcion que llena la tabla de abajo o en la que llena la de arriba?

Comment: No se soluciono

Comment: ¿Qué te muestra ahora?

Comment: Ahora no me aplica datatables en la tabla de abajo

Comment: ¿Es posible que pongas el código funcional en JSFiddle o CodePen? En teoría con mi sugerencia debería funcionar, necesitaría verlo trabajando para poder hacer cambios.